# Drag & drop folders in Silverlight App

Tags: c#, silverlight, drag-and-drop

I have a silverlight upload control. It handles drag&drop for files, quite good.
Users can drag multiple files to the control, and it will upload them.

BUT, I cannot get this to work with folders. I would like to be able to drop a folder onto the control, and then upload all the files in the folder.

I'm having alot of problems, detecting that it is a folder though, and not a file. It seems the `DragEventArg`'s data, is `FileInfo[]`. I've tried everything I can think off, to check every `FileInfo` in the array. Most of my attempts seems to be un-allowed in silverlight. The rest, has no effect.

This is an internal application, hosted on our intranet.

Can I parse it somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silverlight does not allow direct access to the file-system (except with raised intranet privileges and in OOB mode).

The *files* you access were via streams and not directly. Folder access is not allowed by default but you can make your app a Trusted application on an Intranet.

[Trusted Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721083%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

> In Silverlight 5, trusted applications have additional capabilities
>   unavailable in previous versions of Silverlight. Specifically,
>   Silverlight 5 trusted applications can do the following:
>
> Access the local file system without restrictions.
>
> Access security critical methods without a MethodAccessException occurring. This is supported for Windows-based applications only.
>
> Run inside the browser if the computer and application are properly configured, as previously mentioned.
>
> Create multiple windows when running outside the browser.

Comment: Internally. It is an intranet solution.

Comment: You say that folder access is not allowed by default. Does that mean I can enable it, without going OOB?

Comment: You can make it a trusted application on an Intranet. I have updated the answer with a link.